# How can I bind the template without calling fixture.detectChanges()?

Tags: angular, karma-jasmine, angular-lifecycle-hooks

I am fixing/adding unit tests to an existing application. Below is the patterns that the code follows. Methods call other methods. Unit tests use some mock classes.

Calling **fixture.detectChanges()** is calling **ngOnInit()**, which calls all the rest of the methods in chain. All I want is to call one method, **methodC()**.

The reason I am calling **fixture.detectChanges()** is to bind new values to the template. Is there a way to do so without calling **fixture.detectChanges()**?

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit {
  property1: any;
  property2: any

  constructor(
    private service1: Service1,
    private service2: Service2,
    ){}
   
  ngOnInit() {
    this.methodA();
  }

  methodA(){
    this.methodB();
  }
  

  methodB(){
     this.service1.doThis();
     this.service2.doThat()
         .subscribe(result => {
             this.property1 = result
             this.methodC()
      });
  }

   methodC(){
      //do something with PROPERTY1
      this.property2 = ...someValue;
   }
 }
```

Here the template

```
 <div class="class1" *ngIf="property2?.value === 'someValue1'">
    Pending purchase 
 </div>
 <div class="class2" *ngIf="property2?.value === 'someValue2'">
    Order Submitted 
 </div>
```

My unit test

```
  it('should display pending purchase if amount is null or undefined', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();    //--> THIS WILL RUN THE LIFECYCLE 
      
      component.property1 = {}    //SOME VALUE
      component.methodC().        //RUN THE LOGIC TO PRODUCE A VALUE FOR property2

      //fixture.detectChanges();  // THIS IS RUNNING EVERYTHING AND OVERRIDE NEW VALUES

      const elt = element.querySelector('.class1');
      expect(elt).not.toBeNull();
  });
```

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Override should do the trick:

```typrscript
it('should display pending purchase if amount is null or undefined', () => {
      const originalOnInitFunc = MyComponent.prototype.ngOnInit;
      const overrideOnInitFunc = () => { };
      MyComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = overrideOnInitFunc; // override ngOnInit

      component.property1 = {};
      component.methodC();

      fixture.detectChanges();

      const elt = element.querySelector('.class1');
      MyComponent.prototype.ngOnInit = originalOnInitFunc; // revert ngOnInit

      expect(elt).not.toBeNull();
   });
```

Comment: I'm getting the error `MyComponent doesn't contain "prototype"`. And when I put a break point inside the `ngOnInit()`, the older implementation is still being executed.